Collection Masks in Grease Pencil Line Art
In Blender's documentation for grease pencil line art, they have an illustration showing the usage of collection masks. It shows different color outlines for different object intersections.

I'm having a hard time understanding how it actually works as it's not really explained, and I'm not finding many people talking about it online. The whole "Collection Masks" interface under the line art modifier's Intersection section mostly -- what does each box correspond to, are they assigned? I can click the first one and see it does something but it's unclear to me.

Edit: I never noticed you could select the collection and that it had settings. I see how it corresponds with the UI with the line art now, but still unclear how exactly it works to get this same result.

Really simple scene but I roughly recreated it if that helps:


If 2 collections have a common square enabled, they will interact. If Exact Match is enabled, they must share the exact same groups (each square must share the same enabled/disabled state). That's how I understand it, but it's only a guess. Each square being a group.
